# Deploy ear with war on jboss eap 6.1

Tags: deployment, jboss, glassfish, ear, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying deploy an ear into JBoss eap 6.1. The structure of the ear is the following:

```
myEar.ear
|
|__
|  lib
|  |
|  |__
|     ALL LIBRARIES
|__
|  META-INF
|  |
|  |__
|  |  maven
|  |  |
|  |  |__
|  |     com.test.testEar
|  |     |
|  |     |__
|  |        testEar
|  |        |
|  |        |__
|  |           pom.properties
|  |           pom.xml
|  |
|  |__
|     application.xml
|     
|__
   myWar1.war
   myWar2.war
   ALL EJBS
```

This ear deploys on Glassfish 2.1 and I don't know why it doesn't deploy on JBoss EAP 6.1.
How to deploy this ear on JBoss6.1?

Comment: How are you trying to deploy, by copying the file to the deployments directory, or via the management console? Do you see any error messages on the logs?

Comment: I try to deploy by copying the file but I don't see any errors messages.